# Fail2ban doesn't persist manual banned IPs after service restart

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, iptables, firewall, fail2ban

Just upgraded from f2b v0.9.6 to v0.10.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 using this [thread](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2308#issuecomment-491438831), and it is banning normally according to my old jails that i copied from my previous version.

But when i restart the service, it persist only the IPs that was banned with the configured enabled jails. All manually banned IPs like `fail2ban-client set sshd banip 1.2.3.4` are gone when i do restart. That wasn't the normal behavior on old versions i used.

Any help please?

**Update:** Just tested (as fresh install and upgrade) f2b on 2 Ubuntu 16.04 servers and it did same behavior. Seems not related to Ubuntu version

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Well, after posting the question i gave it a shot on 16.04, and got same behavior, should i now edit the question or post new one?? as the issue seems to be related to f2b not the Ubuntu version

Comment: Personally I'd delete this question and start a new one. But that's just my opinion (*I've not asked a question here so my opinion is possibly not valuable; but you have multiple close votes already*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common bug in f2b `v0.10.5` on different OSs not Ubuntu only, fixed in `v0.10.6.`

You can find this discussion [here](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2647), they are talking about same issue, and got it fixed by changing to `v0.10.6` or even `v0.11.x`.